# Issue while writing four word in Visual Studio while making SSRS Report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I could not able to write only 4 words of "Weekly" while using expression. Please find the below screenshot and help me with this.
I have made SSRS Report and in Header Section I want to write $300 per week in front of RentalPayment. But the table which I have chosen RentalFrequencies. The values they are having "Weekly" words not "Week".
How can I change that in my expression?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If's not very clear what you want to change but assuming you want to change this part

[image]

and also assuming that that "per weekly" is coming from your RentalFrequencies field then if you just want to replace the phrase "per Weekly" in your dataset with "per Week", you can do something like this.

```
=Replace(Fields!RentalFrequencies.Value, "per Weekly", " per week")
```

I've added a space to the start of the replacement string so it reads better.